# When hover removeClass, addClass to the class the removed when mouseenter another dive

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseenter

```
<script>
$('.image-wrapper').mouseenter(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).removeClass('image-wrapper');
});

$('.boxer').mouseenter(function(){
  $('.image_wrapper img').addClass('image_wrapper img:hover');
});
</script>
```

As you can see I removeClass for my background `<div>` hover effect. So when I select another `<div>` then only let the background `<div>` make hover.

Update* I try this also.

```
<script>
var background = document.getElementById('.image-wrapper');
var background = false ;

$('.image-wrapper').mouseenter(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).removeClass('image-wrapper');
    background = true;
 });

$('.boxer').mouseenter(function(){
    if (background = true) {
        $('.image-wrapper').addClass('image-wrapper');
    } else {
        $('.image-wrapper').removeClass('image-wrapper');
    }
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="info_01" class="image-wrapper info_all">
    <img src="images/main_2/info_01.jpg" alt="" class="images">
    <div class="boxer"><p class="boxer_title">ABOUT</p></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#info_01 {
    width:512px;
    height:384px;
    background:no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
}

.image-wrapper {
  font-size: 0;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.image-wrapper img {
  max-width: 100%;
  transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
}

.image-wrapper:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.1); 
}
```

Comment: If you remove `.image-wrapper` class of the element, the second function will bot find the element. Show more code for us to understand what you really want to do. Because right now, what you ask is unclear,.

Comment: I'm not sure how to tell. But maybe I can explain to you. Lets say I have a <div1> with w:50px h:50px, now when I hover it scale to 1.1, Then I have a <div2> inside the <div1> with w:10px h:10px, So now I do a Jquery to remove the <div1> hover effect. Then now when I move my mouse to the <div2>, <div1> start doing hover.

Comment: May I know can document.getElementById('.class'); because of get element by 'ID' but at the end I use .class is it okay?

Comment: `document.getElementById()` is a Javascript method to select an element. It absolutely need an `id`. If you want to select a class, use [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp)

Comment: But my point is... If you first remove the class from the element, you CAN'T use this class to select the element in your second function... Since this class has been removed. Show your HTML and CSS (if you have)... And maybe we'll find a solution.

Comment: `$('.image-wrapper').addClass('image-wrapper');` doesn't do anything. It's a non-sense. And `$('.image-wrapper').removeClass('image-wrapper');` just remove the "hook" you had before to select the element. After that, the is NO element with class `image-wrapper`... So nothing will happen.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I added the HTML & CSS. So if the hook is removed which mean I should do .addClass('image-wrapper-01') another class?

Answer (score 0):

With your HTML and CSS, it is easier to understand what you try to achieve.
You should always include it for your future questions.

And describe what you want as a result.
So, here... You want the text below the image to appear at the same time the image scales up.

I changed the name of `image-wrapper` css rule for `font-zero`... Which is more descriptive of its real effect.

The jQuery method I used is [`.hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)
There is two functions that act as event `handlers` for mouseenter and mouseleave.

**About selecting elements by class versus adding and removing it:**
Use "stable" selectors to target elements.

The classes you add and remove shouldn't also be used as selector...
Unless you want to "prevent" a function to trigger...
Do not expect a function to trigger if the selector has been removed.
This is where you lost yourself.

There is a big bunch of jQuery method you can use that will simplify your scripts.
I suggest you bookmark [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_events.asp).

```js
$('#info_01 img').hover(
 function(e) {
  $(this).parent().removeClass('font-zero');
 },
 function(){
  $(this).parent().addClass('font-zero');
});
```

```css
#info_01 {
  width:512px;
  height:384px;
  background:no-repeat;
  position:absolute;
}

.font-zero {
  font-size: 0;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.image-wrapper img {
  max-width: 100%;
  transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
}

.image-wrapper:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.1); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="info_01" class="image-wrapper font-zero">
 <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRlOChoWeklUXYE3aE4hIbKIwDKheJoxvHWkcjAeSF2fXxDDtvZ" alt="" class="images">
 <div class="boxer"><p class="boxer_title">ABOUT</p></div>
</div>
```